# Angular lazy loading sibling applications which are on different environments.

Tags: angular, webpack, runtime, angular2-routing, lazy-loading

I'm currently working on a project where our lead architect wants to load up different 'sibling' application in an angular application dynamically in run-time. I already know how this can be done using modules with lazy loading. But in our case the applications also exist separately on their own environment. Does anyone have advice on how to achieve this the angular way?

I already tried working them out into their own chunks and load them up like that and it is partially working. but the 'main' app needs to be aware of the sibling applications and therefore it needs to be adjusted to lazy load the modules.

I'm mostly curious about solutions other people used in these type of scenarios :)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Recently, I have started a project with multiple apps at work. Our application has two different kinds of users, regular users and managers. Most of the screens are the same with minor differences. But there are some menus that regular users cannot see and there are some actions users cannot take. Instead of having bunch of `*ngIf`s within the application, we decided to utilize `angular-cli` multiple application support. You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-multiple-apps)

Basically, what you need to do is

within `.angular-cli.json`, add another app to your `apps` array.

```
"apps": [
  {
    "name": "manager-app",
    "root": "src/manager-app",
    "assets": [
      "assets",
      {
        "glob": "**/*",
        "input": "../common/assets/",
        "output": "./assets",
        "allowOutsideOutDir": true
      }
    ],
    .... // bunch of other configs
  },
  {
    "name": "user-app",
    "root": "src/user-app",
    "assets": [
      "assets",
      {
        "glob": "**/*",
        "input": "../common/assets/",
        "output": "./assets",
        "allowOutsideOutDir": true
      }
    ],
    ....
  },
  {
    "name": "common",
    "root": "src/common",
    "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
    "appRoot": "src"
  }
]
```

So, I have three apps, `manager-app`, `user-app`, `common`. `manager` and `user` apps have their own environments, configs, routing setups etc. I run `ng build` for each of them separately.

Also, I have `common` app which contains shared components, services, modules, assets files etc.

In order to access `common` assets from both application, you need to add following json to `assets` array of each application in `.angular-cli.json`

```
{
    "glob": "**/*",
    "input": "../common/assets/",
    "output": "./assets",
    "allowOutsideOutDir": true
}
```

When you want to run them side by side,

manager-app -> `ng serve --port 8080 --app=manager-app`

user-app -> `ng serve --port 8081 --app=user-app`

When you want to build them same thing applies,

manager-app -> `ng build --prod --app=manager-app`

user-app -> `ng build --prod --app=user-app`

This will generate two different `dist` folder which you define for each of them in `.angular-cli.json`. i.e `apps[0].outDir`

Also, there is a tool called Nx which helps you manage multiple apps at the same time. 
You can take a look at this [example](https://github.com/nrwl/nx-examples). 
For more information about Nx, check it [here](https://github.com/nrwl/nx).

Also, for AoT compiler to work with components from `common` app, you need to include those modules in `tsconfig.app.json` of each application.

`manager-app/tsconfig.app.json`

```
{
    ...
    "include": [
        "**/*.ts",
        "../common/app/my-component/my-component.module.ts"
    ]
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hey man! thanks for the quick reply! Sounds solid indeed! I tried to use Nx for my own situation, but in our situation its more of an application that act as a 'shell' for the other applications in which we want to lazy-load a specific application into the shell. If you would have components in the 'user' app that needs to be accessible in the 'manager' app would you by default put them in the common app? and how would you update a specific module without rebuilding/rebundling the entire application (I'm not even sure this is possible with webpack) ?

Comment: I would put those modules and components in common app. I actually have one big page that is almost exact for both user and manager. That page has its own route and everything. I put it in common app and pass some config through routing from each application. Also, angular-cli is capable of rebuilding only smart part of your application. So, I would assume that when you change something in the common app, angular-cli would only update that part and reload the application really fast.

Comment: Cool man, let me discuss this with the team as one of the go to solutions! I myself don't even see the sense of sharing components cross 'application' without putting it in the shared/common module.. that's where it's for if you'd asked me. Thanks!

Comment: I've nailed down the way the organization wants to structure things, they want to be able to update applications or install new applications in time. I think we're looking for a Microservice/Micro front end approach, you have any experience with this?

Comment: No, I have not.

Comment: you can't maintain and deploy separately. it's a big drawback.